# How to access the NTAG213 NFC interaction counter?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, nxp-microcontroller, open-nfc

I'm working on an android app where I need to find the number of times an NFC tag was read. I've gone through the docs on the NFC forum and for NTAG213** there is a  field called the MIRROR_CONF using which one can determine whether the interaction counter is enabled/disabled and the value of the counter. I need to access this counter programmatically. I would highly appreciated if someone could help me out with that. It's my third day trying to deal with this now.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in section 2 of [the "Advanced Features" manual of the NXP tagwriter app.](https://inspire.nxp.com/tagwriter/tag-writer-user-manual.pdf)

Basically, you have to have use the NFC-tag to point the device scanning the tag, to some url and then you can append the current counter-value as a parameter to that url.

Unfortunately there seems to be no other way to access the interaction counter.